# Overwrite Assets using assetic

Tags: php, twig, assetic

I have a project that uses assets coming from different source folders. Some of those assets might overwrite others. I would like to reference an asset in a twig template. If the asset exists in more than one of the source folders, the first one should be choosen (eg the design image overwrites the module image). I intended to use the `kriswallsmith/assetic` package but can't find any way to specify multiple root folders.
What I want is something like `Twig_Loader_Filesystem::addPath` but for assets.

Example:

Source folders:

- `assets/design` (contains `images/red.jpg` besides other assets)
- `assets/module` (contains `images/red.jpg` besides other assets)

In the twig template I want to reference

```
{% image 'images/red.jpg' %}<img src="{{ asset_url }}" />{% endimage %}
```

the library should now choose the image `assets/design/images/red.jpg`

Is this possible with the assetic library?
If I need to extend any classes, can you give me some pointers?
Or is there another library that would fit my need better?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I realized how to solve my question:

I must extend AssetFactory and overwrite the parseInput method. I came up with the following solution:

```
use Assetic\Asset\AssetInterface;
use Assetic\Factory\AssetFactory;

class MyAssetFactory extends AssetFactory
{
    /**
     * @var string[]
     */
    private $rootFolders;

    /**
     * @param string[] $rootFolders
     * @param bool   $debug
     */
    public function __construct($rootFolders, $debug = false)
    {
        if (empty($rootFolders)) {
            throw new \Exception('there must be at least one folder');
        }

        parent::__construct($rootFolders[0], $debug);

        $this->rootFolders = $rootFolders;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $input
     * @param array  $options
     * @return AssetInterface an asset
     */
    protected function parseInput($input, array $options = array())
    {
        // let the parent handle references, http assets, absolute path and glob assets
        if ('@' == $input[0] || false !== strpos($input, '://') || 0 === strpos($input, '//') || self::isAbsolutePath($input) || false !== strpos($input, '*')) {
            return parent::parseInput($input, $options);
        }

        // now we have a relatve path eg js/file.js
        // let's match it with the given rootFolders
        $root = '';
        $path = $input;
        foreach ($this->rootFolders as $root) {
            if (file_exists($root . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $input)) {
                $path = $input;
                $input = $root . $path;
                break;
            }
        }

        // TODO: what to do, if the asset was not found..?

        return $this->createFileAsset($input, $root, $path, $options['vars']);
    }

    /**
     * copied from AssetFactory, as it was private
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @return bool
     */
    private static function isAbsolutePath($path)
    {
        return '/' == $path[0] || '\\' == $path[0] || (3 < strlen($path) && ctype_alpha($path[0]) && $path[1] == ':' && ('\\' == $path[2] || '/' == $path[2]));
    }
}
```

Now I can create a new factory with different source folders.

```
$factory = new MyAssetFactory(array('/folder/alpha/', '/folder/beta/'));
// $factory->set some stuff
$twig->addExtension(new AsseticExtension($factory));
```